# Percent rank won't go up to 1

Tags: sql, window-functions

I've written something along the lines of

```
percent_rank() over (partition by (case when date is not null then 1 else 0 end) order by ID ) AS percent_rank
```

and my results only go from 0 to 0.17 not 0 to 1. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this resolve you're issue? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144009/percent-rank-does-not-distribute-over-100

Comment: It does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Hi Sully. Can you include a minimal data set that demonstrates the problem? What I mean is: add the create/insert statements in a table, then include the query that selects from that table.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is duplicates.  It means that about 83% of your data all has the highest value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ecc6d5a23f91de77d9fa32c6d79a5a7) is a simple db<>fiddle illustrating the issue.

I suspect that `NULL` values are involved.  You are testing for `NULL`s -- but that is not in the column used for ordering.

Comment: I think you are right here. What is the best method of fixing it?

Comment: @Sully . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  Ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Clearly, it is not `percent_rank()`.